# Unable to split String element and append to <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***Funtionality:***

I have a String `A,4.0,00:04`. The main purpose to Split the String is to append the value of `00:04` to the following div of "min" and "sec", hence, i will need to further split the value of `00:04` such that when i append the value it will be displayed as "00 min" "04 sec".

***Issue:***

At this point  I am unable to to split further than the "," and when i do my console.log on the Split string, it will return the individual String element of A| 4.0| 00:04.

However, at this point, I do not know how to proceed further to take out the individual element of "00" and "04" to append to the "min" & "sec" div tag.

Please help.

```js
var data = 'A,4.0,00:04';
console.log("BestTime: " + data);
//When I consolelog BESTTIME, it will return the element of (A, 4.0, 00:04)

var TimerList = data.split(",");
console.log("TimerList: " + TimerList[0] + "|" + TimerList[1] + "|" + TimerList[2]);

//TimerList[0] => A //Not What I want to append to div tag
//TimerList[1] => 4.0 // Not What I want to append to div tag
//TimerList[2] => 00:04 //Need to futher split this so that I can append 00 to Game_BestTimer_Minute & 04 to Game_BestTimer_Second

//append BEST GAME TIME to SCOREBOARD
$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute").html(TimerList[2]);
$("#Game_BestTimer_Second").html(TimerList[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Game_BestTimer_Minute" style="font-family:'Avenir';"></div>

<div id="Game_BestTimer_Second" style="font-family:'Avenir';"></div>
```

Comment: Alright, Brain freeze moment. Got it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+(?=:)|\d+$/g` to match one or more digit characters followed by `":"` or digits at end of string to get array containing `["00", "04"]`.

Use multiple selectors at `jQuery()` to make single call to `.html(function)`

```js
var data = 'A,4.0,00:04';
var TimerList = data.match(/\d+(?=:)|\d+$/g);

console.log(TimerList);

$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute, #Game_BestTimer_Second")
.html(function(index, _) {
  return TimerList[index]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="Game_BestTimer_Minute" style="font-family:'Avenir';"></div>
<div id="Game_BestTimer_Second" style="font-family:'Avenir';"></div>
```

Comment: `$/g`? You expecting multi-line strings? BTW, that `.html(fn)` thing is pretty slick

Comment: @Phil Do you mean `g` flag?

Comment: Yeah, having an end-of-line anchor and global flag seems a bit odd is all

Comment: @Phil There is an `OR` `|`. `\d+$` only matches digits at end of string. Without `g`, would only match `\d{2}(?=:)`. Updated first match to `\d+(?=:)`, saves two characters and should return same result.

Comment: Ah yes, my brain separated the anchor from the rest of the expression. Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data1 = "A,4.0,00:04";
var data = data1.split(",")[2]
var min = data.split(":")[0]
var sec = data.split(":")[1]
console.log("BestTime: " + data );

//var TimerList = data.split(",");
console.log("TimerList: " + data + "|" + min + "|" + sec);

//TimerList[0] => A //Not What I want to append to div tag
//TimerList[1] => 4.0 // Not What I want to append to div tag
//TimerList[2] => 00:04 //Need to futher split this so that I can append 00 to Game_BestTimer_Minute & 04 to Game_BestTimer_Second

//append BEST GAME TIME to SCOREBOARD
$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute").html(min);
$("#Game_BestTimer_Second").html(sec);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Game_BestTimer_Minute" style="z-index:10; position:absolute; top:450px; left:870px; font-size:160px; font-family:'Avenir'; width:1080px; color:#fff;"></div>

<div id="Game_BestTimer_Second" style="z-index:10; position:absolute; top:450px; left:1215px; font-size:160px; font-family:'Avenir'; width:1080px; color:#fff;"></div>
```

Split again the data using `":"`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as below?

```
var value = TimerList[2].split(':');

$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute").html(value[0]);
$("#Game_BestTimer_Second").html(value[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Great, but I wonder why you don't split again. Remember call trim to remove space.

```
var TimerList = data.split(",");
console.log("TimerList: " + TimerList[0] + "|" + TimerList[1] + "|" +     TimerList[2]);
var timerList = TimerList[2].split(":");
//append BEST GAME TIME to SCOREBOARD
```

$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute").html(timerList[0].trim());
  $("#Game_BestTimer_Second").html(timerList[1].trim());

Answer (score 1):

Just call `.split()` again, using a colon instead of a comma as the delimiter.

Also note that it is much faster to use `.text()` than `.html()` to insert your values into the DOM.

```js
var data = "A,4.0,00:04"

console.log("BestTime: " + data);

var TimerList = data.split(",");
console.log("TimerList: " + TimerList[0] + "|" + TimerList[1] + "|" + TimerList[2]);

//TimerList[0] => A //Not What I want to append to div tag
//TimerList[1] => 4.0 // Not What I want to append to div tag
//TimerList[2] => 00:04 //Need to futher split this so that I can append 00 to Game_BestTimer_Minute & 04 to Game_BestTimer_Second

var MinSec = TimerList[2].split(":");

//append BEST GAME TIME to SCOREBOARD
$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute").text(MinSec[0]);
$("#Game_BestTimer_Second").text(MinSec[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Game_BestTimer_Minute"></div>
<div id="Game_BestTimer_Second"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems more fitting to use a regular expression to look for `\d+:\d+` at the end of the string...

```js
var data = 'A,4.0,00:04';
console.log("BestTime: " + data);

var [match, min, sec] = data.match(/(\d+):(\d+)$/)

$("#Game_BestTimer_Minute").html(min);
$("#Game_BestTimer_Second").html(sec);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Game_BestTimer_Minute" style="font-family:'Avenir';"></div>

<div id="Game_BestTimer_Second" style="font-family:'Avenir';"></div>
```

Comment: If `match` is not needed `var [, min, sec] = data.match(/(\d+):(\d+)$/)`

Comment: @guest271314 cheers, just wanted to make sure OP noticed there were 3 results