# Unable to populate a list of data into table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

***Functionality:***

I have a String of data =>("A, 4.0. 00:04@B,5.0,00:05@C,9.0,00:09@......"). The String will be split into individual element, and the individual element will be appended to the  tag in the table. Whereby, it will look like:

1. A 00:04
2. B 00:05
3. C 00:09
   ....
4. G 00:29

***Issue:***

Currently, the entire table just looks like this:

1. G 00:29
   2.
   3.
   .....
   10.

Hence, the last value of the data is just appended to the first row of the table.
I am not sure if this is the correct method of populating the  within the . Please help.

***Code:***

```js
console.log("Leaderboard: " + data);
var playerList = data.split("@");

var innerList;
for (i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
  innerList = playerList[i].split(",");
  console.log(innerList[0] + "|" + innerList[1] + "|" + innerList[2]);

  //innerList[0] ==> A to be appended to Player_Name
  //innerList[1] ==> 4.0 not needed to be appended
  //innerList[2] ==> 00:04 to be appended to Player_Score
  $("#Player_Name").html(innerList[0]);
  $("#Player_Score").html(innerList[2]);
}
```

```css
#Rugby_Scoreboard {
  position: absolute;
  left: 335px;
  top: 182px;
  width: 825px;
  height: 818px;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!-- ScoreBoard -Table form-->
<div id="Game_LeaderBoard" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:0px; left:0px; width: 1920px; heigth: 1000px; margin:auto;">

  <table id="Rugby_Scoreboard">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="Player_Name" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:5px; left:150px; font-size:40px; font-family:'OpenSans-Light'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
          <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div id="Player_Score" style="z-index:50; position:absolute; top:5px; left:700px; font-size:40px; font-family:'OpenSans-Light'; width:1080; color:#fff;">
          <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try using regular expressions if you need complicated text matching.

Comment: @gyre what do you mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Luke Are you going to branch off into a 4th branch from this question? I had made a complete answer for question #2, then I had thought you got your answer because I saw question #1 and had mistaken it for question #2. Or is this question #4 and I was going to answer #3? 0_o

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639291/unable-to-split-string-element-and-append-to-div

Comment: @Luke See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Luke Normally I'd vote to close and downvote, but your questions are well structured compared to the majority of questions I've read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use destructuring assignment and trailing comma to exclude `4.0` from result of `.split()`, use multiple selectors at `jQuery()`, call `.html(function)` to set `html` of both elements

```js
var data = "A,4.0,00:04@B,5.0,00:05@C,9.0,00:09";
console.log("Leaderboard: " + data);
var playerList = data.split("@");
console.log(playerList)

var innerList;
for (i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
  var [name,,score] = playerList[i].split(",");
  
  //innerList[0] ==> A to be appended to Player_Name
  //innerList[1] ==> 4.0 not needed to be appended
  //innerList[2] ==> 00:04 to be appended to Player_Score
  $("#Player_Name, #Player_Score")
  .html(function(index, html) {
    var prop = index === 0 ? name : score;
    return html + prop + "<br>"
  })
}
```

```css
/*
#Rugby_Scoreboard {
  position: absolute;
  left: 335px;
  top: 182px;
  width: 825px;
  height: 818px;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ScoreBoard -Table form-->
<div id="Game_LeaderBoard" style="">

  <table id="Rugby_Scoreboard">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="Player_Name" style="">
          <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div id="Player_Score" style="">
          <font face="OpenSans-Light"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: how do you explain this line: `var prop = index === 0 ? name : score;`. looks darn familiar with regards to the `?` and `:`

Comment: If `index` is equal to `0` the current element is `#Player_Name`, set `.innerHTML` to old `.innerHTML` with `name` and `<br>` concatenated, else current element is `#Player_Score`, set `.innerHTML` to old `.innerHTML` with `score` with `<br>` concatenated. See [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I would like to further ask what if there are 3 <div> tags that needs to be appended. Would it be impossible for me to use this "Conditional (ternary) Operator"?? For example, if i were to append the player name, playerTime_Minute and finally playerTime_Second, considering the fact that I could still split the time into individual minute and second.

Comment: @Luke You can use the same approach at `javascript` at Answer. Consider including details of requirements within text body of actual Question, rather than adding requirements at comments not present at original Question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641246/unable-to-populate-a-list-of-data-into-table-dynamically/42641780#comment72410082_42641246

Answer (score 0):

All this code is doing is replacing the contents of a set of elements.

With this part inside the loop:

```
$("#Player_Name").html(innerList[0]);
$("#Player_Score").html(innerList[2]);
```

You're replacing the same contents over and over.

If you want each of the values to show in the table, you need to create new `<tr>` elements and append them to the end of the `<table>` element.

```
$('#Rugby_Scoreboard').append('<tr><td><div id="Player_Name_' + innerList[0] + '">' + 
                                    innerList[2] + 
                              '</div></td></tr>`);
```